# Script to delete duplicate files with same names but different extensions

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I am using Audacity's Chains scripting function to batch-convert and edit many large, uncompressed .WAV files at once to a much smaller .OGG format. I end up with a folder structure like the following:

```
f:/sound-recordings:
-- rec1.wav
-- rec2.wav
-- rec3.wav
-- rec4.wav
-- rec5.wav
f:/sound-recordings/cleaned:
-- rec1.ogg
-- rec2.ogg
-- rec3.ogg
```

Some of the source .WAV files are corrupted (note rec4.wav and rec5.wav in above example), and Audacity will not convert them (at least through the chains function). This creates a problem, as it can become very tedious to compare the two folders, and delete only the .WAV files which were successfully converted to .OGG.

In the example above, "rec1.wav", "rec2.wav", and "rec3.wav" should be deleted, while "rec4.wav" and "rec5.wav" are untouched, since they weren't converted.

I need a script (batch or python preferred) to delete any .WAV files from the main folder, that have identically named .OGG files located in the "cleaned" folder, leaving other .WAV files untouched.

Comment: Have you tried solving the problem yourself? If yes, show us the code and we will help.

Comment: If you want to do it as a batch file it is a simple `FOR` command to iterate through all the .wav files and then use an `IF EXIST` to see if the corresponding .ogg file was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off

for %%I in (f:\sound-recordings\*.wav) do (
    if exist f:\sound-recordings\cleaned\%%~nI.ogg del %%I
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of the elements in the clean directory, using `split` to strip off the extension and then iterator through the dirty directory checking if it is `in` clean.

Basic python pseudo-code would look like:

```
clean = [filename.split('.')[0] for filename in clean_directory]
delete = [filename for filename in dirty_directory if filename.split('.')[0] in clean]
for filename in delete:
    os.remove(filename)
```