# Delete duplicate files of different extensions recursively

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line

I'm trying to create a batch file that can delete .xmlb files is there is a .engb file of the same name in the same folder. I want it to work so that it can check the folder where the batch file is placed as well as all of the sub-folders. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659539/script-to-delete-duplicate-files-with-same-names-but-different-extensions) where someone pointed out how to do this in a single folder, but I'm trying to do it in every sub folder. Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off
    for /r %%I in (*.xmlb) do (
        if exist %%~pnI.engb del %%I
    )
    pause
```

It gives me a "the system cannot find the path specified" error. I tried changing `del` with `echo`, and when I do that it does manage to display the names of the .xmlb files (with .engb extensions), so I'm assuming it can actually find them and my syntax is off somewhere. If I try to use %%~nI like the original code, it won't do anything (because the .engb files are in the same folders as the .xmlb files). I'm sure I'm probably missing some small thing that's preventing it from deleting the right files. Any help is appreciated! I'm attaching two screenshots: one with the batch file in a folder, and then one of the sub-folders that contains .xmlb and .engb files. So in the jungle1, jungle2, and jungle3 folders I want to keep the .engb files and remove any .xmlb files with the same names as .engb files

[image: Folder with the batch file]
[image: Example of a folder with xmlb and engb files]

Comment: Try: `if exist "%%~pnI.engb" del "%%I"`, that is, enclose in quotes both names

Comment: Why not use `If Exist "%%~dpnI.engb" Del /A /F "%%I"`?

Comment: reverse your logic: `for /r %%I in (*.engb) do del "%%dpnI.xmlb" 2>nul`. `2>nul`  supresses the errormessages when trying to delete a non-existing file.

Comment: Putting quotes around it worked!

Edit: All the above solutions seem to help. Thanks!